# Pagination_by в django

Tags: python, django

Прописав в view в своем классе, наследуемом от DetailView  **pagination_by=60**, django генерирует ссылки с префиксом mysite.ru**/?offset=60&**. И вот появилась надобность избавиться от знака **&** в конце ссылок. Жду вашей помощи.

Comment: Django не генерирует ссылок для паджинации, это должен делать программист. Либо вы делаете это в шаблоне (и тогда неплохо бы привести шаблон), либо вы используете какую-то стороннюю библиотеку (и тогда надо знать, какую).

Comment: Ну и да, в `DetailView` паджинации вообще нет. Разбирайтесь со своим кодом, что-то там не то.

Comment: Был бы свой код, ориентировался лучше, разбирал пример другого. Спасибо, порылся в templates и удалил там '&', на самом деле думал, там будет понакрученнее всё.